# Error con popover al cambiar de select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cuando tengo el puntero sobre algún ítem de la lista, el `popover` se hace visible:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aquí es donde viene el problema, al realizar el cambio del `select`, el `popover` se queda visible y no se destruye:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté poner el siguiente código para que al realizar el **reload** también escondiera el `popover`, pero no funcionó.

```
    function reloadAvailableTable(manufacturerIds, categoryIds, textSearch) {
        manufacturerIdFilter = manufacturerIds;
        categoryIdFilter = categoryIds;
        dscFilter = textSearch;


        $('#availableElements').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        console.log("Se realiza el reload");
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
```

**Construcción del popover**

```
 iContent = contentPopover(manufacturerDsc, brandDsc, categoryDsc, subcategoryDsc, segmentDsc);

                    $('#brand-segment-id-' + brandSegmentId).popover({
                        container: '.content-lists',
                        html: true,
                        title: iTitle,
                        content: iContent,
                        placement: 'left',
                        boundary: 'viewport'
                    }).popover('show');
```

Comment: Como declaras el popover?

Comment: Hola Alan, actualizaré mi pregunta para agregar el código de cómo se construye el popover ya que son dinámicos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregar `trigger: "focus"` asi:

```
iContent = contentPopover(manufacturerDsc, brandDsc, categoryDsc, subcategoryDsc, segmentDsc);

                $('#brand-segment-id-' + brandSegmentId).popover({
                    container: '.content-lists',
                    html: true,
                    title: iTitle,
                    content: iContent,
                    placement: 'left',
                    boundary: 'viewport',
                    trigger: 'focus'
                }).popover('show');
```

Comment: No funcionó, aun se sigue quedando

Comment: Quiero pensar que el reload lo hace muy rapido y no se alcanza a destruir el popover al cambiar de sección en el select

Comment: Ya intentaste con `destroy` en lugar de `hide`?

Comment: si leí sobre esa propiedad pero dentro de la documentación no la encontré, pero igual probare con esa propiedad

Comment: Intenta usar clases en lugar de ids, de esa forma puedes usar la clase para esconder el popover.